# Find the physical address of exception vector table from kernel module

Tags: android, memory-management, linux-kernel, arm

I have an android device - Samsung galaxy s2 with kernel version 2.6.35.14 (arm cortex a9)

I tried to find the physical address of the exception vector table. I Know that it is at 0xffff0000 virtual address. (i can print its value via kernel module)

I also know that the translation of most of the kernel virtual address (to physical) is done by substation of the value 0x8000000.

I have a device that can read data directly from devices memory and i want to get the exception vector table.

when i built a kernel module and tried to use the macro virt_to_phys(0xffff0000) i have got some address but the table is not there. i succeed to find in this way the system call table but here the macro gave me wrong address.

Does anyone know why this happens? does the address of the exception vector table resides in a special physical address? Does the kernel translates its address in some special way?

thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is also possible to use the MMU directly (registers ATS1Cxx and PAR) to perform V=>P translation.  See section B4.2.4 of the [ARM ARM](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0406c/index.html) for the gory details.

If you use the MMU registers this way, you might need to protect against races with other uses of the registers.

This maybe accessed from any kernel driver with the following code,

```
 unsigned int pa;
 asm("\t mcr p15, 0, %0, c7, c8, 2\n"
     "\t isb\n"
     "\t mrc p15, 0, %0, c7, c4, 0\n" : "=r" (pa) : "0" (0xffff0000));
 printk("Vector is %x\n", pa & 0xfffff000);
```

The constants are correct.

- 0xffff0000 is the *high vector* virtual address.
- 0xfffff000 is the mask for 4k pages.

This works only on later series ARM processors such as the **Cortex** series.

Answer (score 6):

The *exception vector table* has remained fairly constant in Linux, from 2.6.35 to the most recent *mainline*.  It is allocated very early in the boot phase and involves the *memblock* boot allocator.  The files involved are [entry-armv.S](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/kernel/entry-armv.S), [traps.c](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/kernel/traps.c), and [vmlinux.lds.S](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/kernel/vmlinux.lds.S) (the linker script) in the kernel directory with [init.c](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/mm/init.c) and [mmu.c](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/mm/mmu.c) in the **mm** (or memory management *ARM* directory).  Also, the *vector table* must be mapped all the time and it is readable by a user process.  This is used by the [kernel user helpers](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/arm/kernel_user_helpers.txt); the helper routines are also mapped to this page.

### An explaination

From *vmlinux.lds.S*,

> The vectors and stubs are relocatable code, and the only thing that matters is their relative offsets

`__vectors_start` represents the code in the vector page and is found in *entry-armv.S*.  However, the function is relocated in *traps.c*.  The *boot allocator* reserves a page for the virtual 0xffff000 address (if high vectors are configured).  In your 2.6.35 kernel, the *memblock* allocator is used in [init.c](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/mm/init.c).  Here [mmu.c's](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/mm/mmu.c?v=2.6.35) `devicemaps_init()` allocates a page by calling `early_alloc()`.  This page doesn't follow the normal kernel address space rules and `virt_to_phys` may not be used as the *virtual address* is forced.

However, a kernel address does exist with the original `memblock_alloc()` return address.  This is the pointer `vector` in `devicemaps_init()`; this address does work with `virt_to_phys` and `phys_to_virt`.

The physical address of `__vectors_start`, etc in *entry-armv.S* can be easily found and a physical address calculated; however, it is discarded at the end of the *init* phase and I think you aren't interested in this.

### An answer

You can call, `memblock_dump_all(void)` and look at `dmesg` and use these pointers to try and locate the `vector` page.  It will be 4k size.  You could alter the `devicemaps_init()` to export the `vector` value.  The only way with an unmodified kernel is to do a walk of the **ARM** mmu tables; that is another story.

Comment: That is to say the `vector` pointer in `devicemaps_init` is a virtual alias of 0xffff0000, which maps to the same physical page.  The reason for the *alias* should be obvious.  Most ARM CPUs need the vector at either 0 or 0xffff0000, although newer ARMs could forgo this.

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer!. so let see if i understood correctly. memblock_alloc() return a virtual address that points the vector table (the variable - vector). In addition the kernel have to map the address 0xffff0000 to the physical address that was allotted earlier. so there are 2 virtual addresses in the kernel that are mapped to the same physical address or after the 0xffff0000 mapping the first one is not relevant?

Comment: `memblock_alloc()` allocates a *normal* physical/virtual pair.  Then in `devicemaps_init()`, a 2nd alias is created to the 0xffff0000.  The first virtual address is relevant and remains active; it is the value of the `vector` pointer in `devicemaps_init()`.  It remains in the MMU tables;  The MMU table is a list of **virt** to **phys**; so two entries point to the same **phys** page.  The 0xffff0000 doesn't follow the normal rules as you observe.

Comment: An important *caveat* with this aliasing.  If you intend to modify one of them (not 0xffff0000), you need to *flush the cache* and *write buffer* or it is possible that the old value can remain for some time (in the 0xffff0000 value in cache).  The cache makes a 2nd copy of the same data and it won't know about aliasing.