# Linux kernel ARM exception stack init

Tags: linux-kernel, stack, arm, interrupt, irq

I am using Linux kernel 3.0.35 on Freescale i.MX6 (ARM Cortex-A9). After running into a kernel OOPS I tried to understand the exception stack initialization. Here is what I have uncovered so far.

In **cpu_init()** in *arch/arm/kernel/setup.c*, I see the exception stack getting initialized:

```
struct stack {
    u32 irq[3];
    u32 abt[3];
    u32 und[3];
} ____cacheline_aligned;

static struct stack stacks[NR_CPUS];

void cpu_init(void)
{
    struct stack *stk = &stacks[cpu];

    ...<snip>

    /*
     * setup stacks for re-entrant exception handlers
     */
    __asm__ (
     "msr   cpsr_c, %1\n\t"
    "add    r14, %0, %2\n\t"
    "mov    sp, r14\n\t"
    "msr    cpsr_c, %3\n\t"
    "add    r14, %0, %4\n\t"
    "mov    sp, r14\n\t"
    "msr    cpsr_c, %5\n\t"
    "add    r14, %0, %6\n\t"
    "mov    sp, r14\n\t"
    "msr    cpsr_c, %7"
        :
        : "r" (stk),
          PLC (PSR_F_BIT | PSR_I_BIT | IRQ_MODE),
          "I" (offsetof(struct stack, irq[0])),
          PLC (PSR_F_BIT | PSR_I_BIT | ABT_MODE),
          "I" (offsetof(struct stack, abt[0])),
          PLC (PSR_F_BIT | PSR_I_BIT | UND_MODE),
          "I" (offsetof(struct stack, und[0])),
          PLC (PSR_F_BIT | PSR_I_BIT | SVC_MODE)
        : "r14");
```

I see that each stack has room for only three words. That is how the macro **vector_stub** in *arch/arm/kernel/entry-armv.S* uses it. It saves R0, LR (*parent PC*) and SPSR (*parent CPSR*) into those three words. Then it jumps to **__irq_svc**. That starts with a macro **svc_entry** which creates a stack frame

```
    .macro  svc_entry, stack_hole=0
 UNWIND(.fnstart        )
 UNWIND(.save {r0 - pc}     )
    sub sp, sp, #(S_FRAME_SIZE + \stack_hole - 4)
```

That is also how I see the disassembled code from KGDB:

```
Dump of assembler code for function __irq_svc:
   0xc01402c0 <+0>:  44 d0 4d e2    sub sp, sp, #68 ; 0x44
   0xc01402c4 <+4>:  04 00 1d e3    tst sp, #4
   0xc01402c8 <+8>:  04 d0 4d 02    subeq   sp, sp, #4
   0xc01402cc <+12>:     fe 1f 8d e8    stm sp, {r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, r6, r7, r8, r9, r10, r11, r12}
   0xc01402d0 <+16>:     0e 00 90 e8    ldm r0, {r1, r2, r3}
   0xc01402d4 <+20>:     30 50 8d e2    add r5, sp, #48 ; 0x30
   0xc01402d8 <+24>:     00 40 e0 e3    mvn r4, #0
   0xc01402dc <+28>:     44 00 8d e2    add r0, sp, #68 ; 0x44
   0xc01402e0 <+32>:     04 00 80 02    addeq   r0, r0, #4
   0xc01402e4 <+36>:     04 10 2d e5    push    {r1}        ; (str r1, [sp, #-4]!)
   0xc01402e8 <+40>:     0e 10 a0 e1    mov r1, lr
   0xc01402ec <+44>:     1f 00 85 e8    stm r5, {r0, r1, r2, r3, r4}
   0xc01402f0 <+48>:     ad 96 a0 e1    lsr r9, sp, #13
   0xc01402f4 <+52>:     89 96 a0 e1    lsl r9, r9, #13
   0xc01402f8 <+56>:     04 80 99 e5    ldr r8, [r9, #4]
   0xc01402fc <+60>:     01 70 88 e2    add r7, r8, #1
   0xc0140300 <+64>:     04 70 89 e5    str r7, [r9, #4]
   0xc0140304 <+68>:     54 50 9f e5    ldr r5, [pc, #84]   ; 0xc0140360
   0xc0140308 <+72>:     00 50 95 e5    ldr r5, [r5]
   0xc014030c <+76>:     0c 60 95 e5    ldr r6, [r5, #12]
   0xc0140310 <+80>:     4c e0 9f e5    ldr lr, [pc, #76]   ; 0xc0140364
   0xc0140314 <+84>:     07 0b c6 e3    bic r0, r6, #7168   ; 0x1c00
   0xc0140318 <+88>:     1d 00 50 e3    cmp r0, #29
   0xc014031c <+92>:     00 00 50 31    cmpcc   r0, r0
   0xc0140320 <+96>:     0e 00 50 11    cmpne   r0, lr
   0xc0140324 <+100>:    00 00 50 21    cmpcs   r0, r0
   0xc0140328 <+104>:    0d 10 a0 11    movne   r1, sp
   0xc014032c <+108>:    28 e0 4f 12    subne   lr, pc, #40 ; 0x28
   0xc0140330 <+112>:    32 eb ff 1a    bne 0xc013b000 <asm_do_IRQ>
   0xc0140334 <+116>:    04 80 89 e5    str r8, [r9, #4]
   0xc0140338 <+120>:    00 00 99 e5    ldr r0, [r9]
   0xc014033c <+124>:    00 00 38 e3    teq r8, #0
   0xc0140340 <+128>:    00 00 a0 13    movne   r0, #0
   0xc0140344 <+132>:    02 00 10 e3    tst r0, #2
   0xc0140348 <+136>:    06 00 00 1b    blne    0xc0140368 <svc_preempt>
   0xc014034c <+140>:    40 40 9d e5    ldr r4, [sp, #64]   ; 0x40
   0xc0140350 <+144>:    04 f0 6f e1    msr SPSR_fsxc, r4
   0xc0140354 <+148>:    1f f0 7f f5    clrex
   0xc0140358 <+152>:    ff ff dd e8    ldm sp, {r0, r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, r6, r7, r8, r9, r10, r11, r12, sp, lr, pc}^
End of assembler dump.
```

During an exception, SP is the banked R13. If I am following correctly, there is **no room** for this frame on that stack. That means I must have missed something. Is there **some other place** where the exception stacks are initialized?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**tl;dr** - We switch modes to supervisor and use that stack.

You are missing the key point of where control is handed to the CPU via the *vector table* **and** the mode is switched.  See: [entry-armv.S and `__vectors_start`](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/arch/arm/kernel/entry-armv.S?id=refs/tags/v3.0.35#n1214).  The [`vector stubs`](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/arch/arm/kernel/entry-armv.S?id=refs/tags/v3.0.35#n1028) is the code where control is initially sent after the `b`ranch in the main vector table.  The `vector_stub` macro saves three items; a corrected `lr`, `r0` and the `spsr` of the excepted mode (as you noted).

The point you miss is, after this all exceptions switch to `SVC_MODE` and as such use the `current` tasks stack, which also has the `thread_info` structure.  *mode switching* is a tough concept to get in ARM system level assembler.  Registers that were previously set are now completely different.  Pay attention to `msr` and `cps` type instructions.  Things can change completely after them; I have been confused by this dozens of times.

The `spsr` is used as an index into a `vector_stub` table, which will **normally** jump to either `__irq_svc` or `__irq_usr`.  Just scroll down to look at the bottom of the *entry-arm.S* which you already found.

Related: [Physical address of ARM-Linux vector table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19275718/find-the-physical-address-of-exception-vector-table-from-kernel-module)

Comment: In this version, `mov r0, sp` is done just before `movs pc, lr`.  The first gives `__irq_svc` a pointer to the saved three words.  The 2nd changes modes.  The macro `svc_entry` uses the `r0` to reload the values.  As interrupts are disabled, this static storage is only used once.

Comment: Ah, in case anyone doesn't know.  The ARM has a different stacks for each mode.  So `sp_irq`, `sp_abt`, `sp_und` and `sp_svc` are all different registers pointing to different stacks.  Linux only uses `sp_svc`, except for the short period that this question asks about.