# ARM - What are the differences in the context switch handling, if IRQ happens in USR mode vs SVC mode?

Tags: linux-kernel, operating-system, arm, linux-device-driver

I am looking at a very old version of the Linux kernel for learning purposes. Specifically the IRQ handler as linked here [IRQ handler](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/kernel/entry-armv.S?v=2.4.37#L917).

My understanding from a typical OS 101 course, is that context switches typically happen when the system takes an IRQ. Consequently using Linux as a reference, I have been trying to understand the following:

1. What are the differences in the IRQ handling, if the IRQ were to happen when system is in USR mode (User-Space) vs if the IRQ were to happen when the system is in the SVC mode (Kernel Space). Because it seems like there are two possible paths __irq_svc and __irq_usr.
2. Secondly, what are the implications of the differences (if any) in the above IRQ handling, on the context switching procedure ?

I would appreciate some insight in this regard.

Comment: @artless-noise I have seen a lot of good answers from you in the ARM domain. Was hoping if you may have some thoughts on this.

Comment: This question on [arm exception stacks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22928904/linux-kernel-arm-exception-stack-init) has the answers. `LCvectors` is the real vector table.  They jump to a *stub*; `vector_IRQ` for IRQs (they are copied, etc in this version).  `vector_IRQ` save some registers, changes modes, and does a *table jump* to `__irq_usr`, `__irq_svc` or `__irq_invalid`.  `irq_usr` and `irq_svc` are mainly the same except `ret_to_user` which will reschedule; the `irq_svc` just returns to where it was.  That code maybe rescheduling as well and it will decide who runs, w. irq noted.