# How can I tell if a virtual address has valid mapping in ARM linux kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, arm

I want to check if a virtual address can be dereferenced without raising segmentation fault.
the virtual address I am talking about is not just untrustworthy user space address. I want to check the kernel virtual address as well.

In x86 Linux kernel, __virt_addr_valid() function can be used to check if the
virtual address has valid mapping.

Is there any equivalent in ARM linux kernel??

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What about `virt_addr_valid()` (no leading underscores)?

Comment: In both cases, these are macros.  See: [Arm memory.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/include/asm/memory.h#L347).  You may use [the *find physical address...* answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19275718/find-the-physical-address-of-exception-vector-table-from-kernel-module) on a Cortex-A CPU to determine if the page has a mapping; I guess the CP15 access has some way to flag it is not mapped.